# How can I solve this problem with baking normal map?

Tags: modeling, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I placed highpoly and lowpoly model evenly. Set Ray Distance: 0.08 m (for any other value the problem continue). I use tiled UVs so I bake for every part of model separately.
**The problem is in the thin places:**
[image]

Comment: hello, are your normals correctly flipped? maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I apologize for the delay, here you can download my project file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EAMRRUgvpzx6uaIUzb4flshfwHxKcH8A?usp=sharing

Comment: it works fine here, I created a new image as you didn't pack yours (32 bit float), and gave a bit of extrusion (0.1), here is what it gives: https://zupimages.net/up/21/23/lu7u.png

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: did the extrusion solve your problem? Always give a bit of extrusion if the high-poly goes a bit beyond the surface of the low-poly

Comment: Yes. It solved.

Answer (score 1):

The high-poly goes a bit beyond the surface of the low-poly, so you need to give a bit of *Extrusion* to your bake (0.1 seems to work)